# Follow post form redirects using Ruby Mechanize

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

We're trying to follow post forms that initialize redirects before showing their content using ruby Mechanize/Nokogiri. One example would be the search form on

http://www.chewtonrose.co.uk/

... if you hit the "search" button on your browser, you get taken to

http://www.chewtonrose.co.uk/AdvancedSearch/tabid/4280/Default.aspx?view=tn

- how could we set up Mechanize to return that second url?
- is Mechanize even the right tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, mechanize is good. I checked in this case you will need to submit WITH the button.

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(<url>)
form = #get form
button = #get button
page2 = agent.submit(form, button)
page2.uri # will show your 2nd url
```